# DbxRecord server modification date timestamp or revision

Tags: android, dropbox-api, datastore

Looking at the Dropbox Datastore API, I could not find a way to easily find records modified after a given date (or revision number). Of course, I can add my own "MODIFICATION_DATE" field, however on different client, the timestamp might be different.

Using the listener does not look convenient and reliable.
Basically I want to sync an Android SQlite table with a Dropbox DbxTable but I'm missing a way to get incremental changes on the Dropbox side, so your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The only way incremental changes are exposed is through the listener/observer, which means that you can only get incremental changes while your app is running.

You could always put a *client* modified time on each record (or perhaps an increasing version number to avoid clock skew problems), but it would be up to you to maintain.